# The result of map sum [[]] is wrong?

Tags: haskell

```hs
sumord = unwords . map (show . sum . filter odd . map ord) . words

sumord "" == ""
```

the value of `sumord ""` should be 0, and it is probably a wrong value of the function `sum`, but `map sum [[]] == [0]` which should be the write result.

Comment: `""` is just syntactic sugar for `[]` - it's an empty list (in this case a list of `Char`s). If you `map` anything over an empty list, you get an empty list back. In your other example, `[[]]` is not empty, it contains a single element (which is itself an empty list).

Comment: @RobinZigmond How would I do for words return [""] instead of [], as I know the Functor rules :)

Answer (score 1):

`map sum [[]]` is fine. You can try it yourself. The problem is that `words ""` is `[]` not `[[]]`, so your `sumords` ends up being `(unwords . map _ . words) ""`, which is `unwords (map _ (words ""))`, which is `unwords (map _ [])` which is `unwords []` which is `""`, not `"0"` as you seem to be expecting.